# Reducers aren't triggered upon dispatch, Redux Toolkit

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, tsx

I am creating a simple todo and i'm using redux toolkit.

My issue is that it seems not to work, there is no error. It just doesn't work.

**TaskPane.tsx**

```
dispatch(addTask(task));
```

**TaskSlice.tsx**

```
const taskSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'tasks',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTask: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      console.log('Add task');
      state.tasksItems = [
        ...state.tasksItems,
        {
          id: Date.now(),
          title: action.payload,
          status: 'todo',
        },
      ];
    },
    justPrint: state => {
      console.log('I am called.');
    },
  },
});
```

Nothing is being printed on console when i dispatch both actions.

I have another slice for modals and it works properly.

Comment: Do you see anything in Redux dev tools?

Comment: If i saw addTask & justPrint there does it mean that they were triggered ? They were there, but nothing was changed in the state.

Comment: Yeah, that means at least the action is being dispatched. Are you registering your reducer correctly in `configureStore()`?

Comment: I think so,
here is my store.tsx


```import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import ModalReducer from '../redux/reducers/ModalSlice';
import TaskReducer from '../../pages/TasksPane/TasksSlice';
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    modals: ModalReducer,
    tasks: TaskReducer,
  },
});```

Comment: Unfortunately, we need more code to look at, to possibly identify the problem. Maybe how you export. Do you see initialState for this reducer in the dev tools?

Comment: yes i can see initial state for this reducer. this is how i export the actions ```export const { addTask, justPrint } = taskSlice.actions;```

Comment: In `taskSlice.tsx` do you `export default taskSlice.reducer`? also the file name above and in the import statement doesn't match

Comment: Yes i exported the reducer as default and the file names not matching is just a typo here. It is really match on my local.

Comment: can you share the code where you are making the dispatch? probably dispatch is not happening

Comment: Sorry, i have already solved the issue. There is no wrong with the code, i simply just restarted by doing ```npm start``` and everything works now. Thank you for helping!